# Index page not rendering on elastic Beanstalk hosted Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need help, I’ve been trying to host a Spring Boot application on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk but once it is hosted it fails to render the home or index page, other pages are being rendering okay. Do you guys have any idea as to why I’m getting this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.